# Accessing to *head and reading from file

Tags: c, list, file, head

I'm writing a program which sorts alphabetically lines in a file.
I want to do this by adding with sorting to the one-way list dynamically allocated.
For test I made a program which reads lines from a file by `fgets` to `char bufor[]` and after this I want to add this to the beginning of a one-way list, but when I want to check if `*head!=NULL`, then I'm getting an error. Where is the problem?

Code below:
I have made structure

```
 typedef struct LISTA lista;
    struct LISTA
    { char*line;
    lista* next;};

void check(int argc,char * argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Uzycie: %s nazwa_pliku\n", argv[0]);
      exit (-1);
    } }
FILE* otworz_plikR(char* namef) // Otwieranie pliku w Trybie READ
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(namef, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open source file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else printf("Source file opened!\n");
    return fp;
}
lista* stworz_liste(char* namef) 
{
    lista **head=NULL;
    char bufor[100];
    char *line;
    lista *tmp;

    *head=NULL;

    size_t* len = 0;

    FILE* fp=otworz_plikR(namef);

    while(fgets(bufor,&len,fp)!=NULL)

    {
        line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (strlen(&bufor) + 1));

        strcpy(line, bufor);  

        printf("%s",line);

        tmp = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));

        tmp->next=NULL;

        tmp->line=line;

        if (*head != NULL) tmp->next = *head;

        *head = tmp;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free (bufor);
    free (len);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

And here is main:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    check(argc,argv);
    lista *head=stworz_liste(argv[5]);
    printf("\n%s",head->line);
    free (head);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help.
argv[3] = output.txt
argv[5] = input.txt.
Maybe you have other problem to solve this problem?

Comment: `lista **head=NULL`. That makes `head` NULL. So you cannot dereference it. That is, `*head` is trying to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: 0) `stworz_liste` does not return a value. 1) `fgets(bufor,&len,fp)` --> `fgets(bufor, sizeof bufor, fp)`

Comment: 2) `free (bufor);
    free (len);` this delete.

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your list builder function, but added more error checking. The method is to create each new node, link it to the existing list, and make it the new head of the list. Finally it returns the list pointer.

```
lista *stworz_liste(char *namef) 
{
    lista *head = NULL;                                 // single indirection
    char bufor[100];
    lista *tmp;
    FILE* fp=otworz_plikR(namef);
    while(fgets(bufor, sizeof(bufor), fp) != NULL)      // replaced len
    {
        bufor [ strcspn(bufor, "\r\n") ] = 0;           // remove trailing newline
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(lista));                    // memory for list item
        if (tmp == NULL)
            exit(1);                                    // error
        tmp->line = malloc(strlen(bufor) + 1);          // simplify, remove &
        if (tmp->line == NULL)
            exit(1);                                    // error
        strcpy(tmp->line, bufor);  
        printf("%s\n",tmp->line);
        tmp->next = head;                               // link to current list
        head = tmp;                                     // new head of list
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //free (bufor);                                     // can't free this
    //fclose(fp);                                       // close once only
    return head;                                        // return head of list
}
```

Comment: What if bufor will get x>100 string and how to protect against that?